# Is wish "I would have" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I've been constantly hearing some people say stuff like this:

> I wish I would've listened to him.

While I can't seem to understand the structure.

Isn't it supposed to be:

> I wish I had listened to him.

Are these the same? What type lf grammar is the first sentence?

Comment: No, it isn't but not everybody  has "educated speech". I wish you would listen to me. Conditional and said in the present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I wish time would stop now or I wish time stopped now](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117015/i-wish-time-would-stop-now-or-i-wish-time-stopped-now)

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional perfect 'I would have' in this way instead of past perfect (e.g. 'I had') is US regional informal or uneducated speech, and regarded by many as an error.

> Correct: I wish I had known.
> Incorrect: I wish I would have known.
>
> Correct: I wish she had told me.
> Incorrect: I wish she would have told me.
>
> Correct: We wish they had been on time.
> Incorrect: We wish they would have been on time.

[Mistake: If I would have… (Lawless English)](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/if-i-would-have/)

Answer (score 1):

"*I wish I would have...*" is a relatively new structure in English. It means the same as "*I wish I had...*". It has become increasingly common roughly since the 1980s, to the point where it's about 10% as common as "I wish I had" according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish%20I%20had%20done%2Cwish%20I%20would%20have%20done&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20I%20had%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20I%20would%20have%20done%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwish%20I%20had%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20I%20would%20have%20done%3B%2Cc0). That's a very significant portion, which means many native speakers of English use this structure naturally. It's even in the title of at least one book: "[The Marriage Advice I Wish I Would Have Had](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XB49ZL6)"

However, many still consider this form bad to be grammar, and the people who use it to be "uneducated". So, I recommend you learn it so you can understand it, but I don't recommend using it unless you're living among people use it naturally.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is a fair compromise.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm a dyed-in-the-wool descriptivist, so it's no compromise for me to say it's correct